# Is there a difference between super.getX() and simply x?

Tags: java

I have a class that has a protected value `x` and I have another class that extends that class.

In the extended class is there any difference between `return super.getX()` and `return x`?

They both can visibly see the variable right? and I was under the impression that the values were exactly the same so is there a reason that my professor said to use `super.getX()` instead of just returning `x`?

example:

```
public int getX(){
    return x;
}
```

vs

```
public int getX(){
    return super.getX();
}
```

The reason for why I have 2 `getX` methods is because the extended `getX` does checks and applies manipulations to the value `x` depending on other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When overriding a method to execute some logic before or after the overridden method, the last one is called with `super.foo()`.

Since you are overriding `getX()` to do checks and apply manipulations to the return value, it is good practice to call the super method with `super.getX()` even if it is a simple getter, because that is what is done when overriding methods.

Calling the superclass method also lets you automatically execute any logic in case the super method is changed. Let's say one day you change `super.getX()`: the change will automatically be reflected when calling `getX()`.

Answer (score 1):

> The reason for why I have 2 "getX" methods is because the extended getX does checks and applies manipulations to the value x depending on other values.

I can use the same reason to answer your question. What if the base class's `getX()` did some "checks and manipulations to the value of x" before returning a value? In that case, `return super.getX()` would return a different value than `return x`.

Even if at the moment the base class method simply returns `x`, that might change in the future. If you want your sub-class's `getX()` to return a value that depends on the value returned by the base class's `getX()` (which may or may not be simply the instance variable `x`), you should use `super.getX()` instead of accessing `x` directly.